# scrollTo plugin not scrolling links outside nav

Tags: javascript, flash

I have the scrollTo script successfully implemented on the nav at [avalonbyeaw.com](http://www.avalonbyeaw.com) and my client wishes to add links from the homepage. Easy, right? I guess not. Not only will it not scroll but it also adds `#finishes` to the URL that we've stripped from the nav links. I'm guessing I just need to add the links to a function somewhere? I can't figure it out.

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a.panel').click(function () {

        $('a.panel').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        current = $(this);

        $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);      

        return false;
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        resizePanel();
    });
});

function resizePanel() {

    width = $(window).width();
    height = $(window).height();

    mask_width = width * $('.item').length;

    $('#debug').html(width  + ' ' + height + ' ' + mask_width);

    //$('#wrapper, .page').css({width: width, height: height});
    //$('#stage').css({width: mask_width, height: height});
    $('#wrapper').scrollTo($('a.selected').attr('href'), 0);
}
```

Working nav link html

```
<div id="nav-finishes" class="nav"><a href="#finishes" class="panel panel-finishes" alt="finishes"><img src="images/spacer.gif" height="10" width="79" border="0" /></a></div>
```

Non-working link added to the piecemaker xml feed

```
<Text>&lt;p&gt;Avalon by EAW features automotive-class finishes on all trim pieces. &lt;a href="#finishes" class="panel"&gt;Optional premium enclosure finishes&lt;/a&gt; set these systems in a class by themselves.&lt;/p&gt;</Text>
```

Comment: ah, would help if i spell finishes right. well it links but it doesn't animate. still can't figure that part out. anyone?

Comment: Do you know how to access the js environment from inside flash?

Comment: All that is happening is your link is having the standard behavior.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does not have the ability to attach click event handlers to the returned XML inside of flash, which is why your script is failing.

**Possible greasy hack:**

Try returning something like this in the XML.

```
&lt;a href="#finishes" onClick="$('#nav-finishes a').trigger('click'); return false;" class="panel"&gt;
```

The idea here is that when a user clicks the link in the xml, it will trigger a virtual click on the main nav, which we know is already working.

**Possible better hack:**

install this jQuery pluggin : http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Then you can do something like this:

```
$(window).hashchange( function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
      $('#wrapper').scrollTo(location.hash, 800); 
});
```

and you can just remove `$('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);`

Comment: no dice, still links as usual and appends the hash to the url

Comment: try with capital C in onClick (my bad)

Comment: still no. the animation, that is. haven't tried the hash problem